# Function to repeat a specific message in a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I was coding something new for my bot, when someone says the letter "h" the bot will repeat the same letter in the chat. However, it seems like the bot did that, but said the message 5 times, and never stopped saying it over and over.

Not only that, when someone said anything, the bot would say h 5 times over, and over, and over.

Here's the code:

```
@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("h") != 1:
            await message.channel.send("h")
```

Comment: You only have code saying "if you found `h` not one time, but any other number of times, send `h`". What you are describing is what your code implies

Comment: And that's what I don't want the bot to do. I want so when someone says a single time the letter h it will repeat it. What happened is that every message made the bot say h.

Answer (score 1):

`on_message` wil react to every message including the bot itself. The best method to ignore bot messages is like this.

```py
@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == bot.user:  # skip bot messages
             return

        # code here

        if message.content.find("h") != 1:
            for _ in range(5):
                await message.channel.send("h")
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because you're indexing the message content starting from **1**, while you should start from **0**:

```
if message.content.find("h") != 0:
```

By the way, if the purpose is ignore bot messages, you can do that explicitly:

```
if message.author != client.user:
    await message.channel.send("h")
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't say it five times now. But any message sent by a user the bot responds with "h", how do I fix that?

Comment: @ItsFireStorm If their messages start with 'h' that's to be expected, it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm trying to make it so when a user sends only the letter h it will return that letter. Not any phrase containing h.